# Create Report based on grouping case status in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

So let us assume a case took 20 hours from open to close. So I needs to put these 20 hours in three groups(In progress, waiting on company, waiting on customer)

No need to worry on who worked/when , what status etc. Just I need to be able to distribute the 20 hours in above example into those three groups. So every case will have one row in the report with these 3 cols with case number.

So that I can figure out during case life cycle how much time is spend on these 3 groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved this by using buckets in reports. I have created three bucket values with mentioned names, grouped the case status accordingly and then generated the matrix report in printable view.

Hope this post will help someone..